# What is the ↵–character in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm pulling in some data from an api and console.log in chrome:

Chrome prints it like 
asdföklajsd↵New line!

I would like to replace the ↵ character with a `<br />` using `replace` in javascript. How do I reference that character?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's a return character.

Try replacing them like this:

```
myString = myString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br />");
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: Here is how I did it however: .replace(/\n/g, '<br />');

Comment: That line might miss out on `return` characters, though. The regex I used makes sure those are removes as well, while guaranteeing that `\r\n` doesn't get replaced with `<br /><br />`.

Comment: @nisar: That's not a newline character. That's the symbol used to visualize a newline: `↵`

Comment: @AbhishekSoni what do you mean, _”Doesn’t work”_? What’s wrong?